# Why it's only working with setting kernel: 'rbf' in SVM Classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, grid-search, supervised-learning

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
    from sklearn import svm
    params_svm = {
        'kernel' : ['linear','rbf','poly'],  
        'C' : [0.1,0.5,1,10,100],             
        'gamma' : [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10]      
    }
    svm_clf = svm.SVC()
    estimator_svm = GridSearchCV(svm_clf,param_grid=params_svm,cv=4,verbose=1,scoring='accuracy')
    estimator_svm.fit(data,labels)
    print(estimator_svm.best_params_)
    estimator_svm.best_score_



/*
   data.shape is (891,9)
   labels.shape is  (891) both are numeric 2-D and 1-D arrays.
*/
```

when I am using GridSearchCV with rbf it's giving the best parameter combination in just 2.7seconds..!
but when I make a list of kernel including any 'poly' or 'linear' separately or with 'rbf' it's taking too long to produce output, i.e. not giving output even after 15-20 minutes, which means I am doing something wrong. I am new to Machine Learning(supervised). I am not able to find any bug in the coding...I am not getting what's going wrong behind the scenes!

Can anyone explain this to me ,what i am doing wrong

Comment: Note that the SVM with 'linear' kernel does not require the gamma parameter - so maybe it's because GridSearchCV is smart enough to not loop over Gamma for the linear model and so it runs faster? Also have you tried simply manually looping over the parameters to ensure each iteration is running correctly?

Answer (score 0):

No you are not doing anything wrong as per your code. There are many factors that come into play here

- SVC is a complex classfier which requires computation of a distance between each pair of points in the dataset.
- The complexity also varies with different kernel. I am not sure but i think it is `O((no_of_samples)^2 * n_features)` for rbf kernel, while it is `O(n_samples*n_features)` for linear kernel. So, it is not the case that just because `rbf kernel` works in 15 mins, then linear kernel will also work in similar time.
- Also the time taken depends drastically on the dataset and the data patterns present in it. For e.g. an rbf kernel may converge quickly with say `C = 0.5` but may take drastically more time for polynomial kernel to converge for the same value of C.
- Also, without using the cache the running time increase a lot. In [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/996/38068), the author mentions it might increase to O(n_samples^3 *n_features).
- Here is the offical documentation [from sklearn about SVM complexity](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#complexity). See [this section](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#tips-on-practical-use) about practical tips on using SVM as well.
- You can set `verbose` to True to see the progress of your classfier and how it is trained.

References

- [GridSearchCV goes to endless execution using SVC](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/989/svm-using-scikit-learn-runs-endlessly-and-never-completes-execution)
- [Computational complexity of SVM](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-computational-complexity-of-an-SVM)
- [Official Documentation of SVM for scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#support-vector-machines)

Comment: Kk thanks...!but why would it take more time in linear/poly svc kernel if it's time complexity is O(n_samples * n_features)  simpler than that of rbf kernel!

Comment: I am not sure though, maybe it has something to do with data... I mean since the data is not linearly separable the linear kernel is taking a lot of time. If this answer solved your problem can you please upvote and Mark it as the correct one :-)

Comment: Also as I mentioned in my 3rd point, without cache, the complexity increases, so that me the case as well. Although without looking at the dataset I can't say for sure.